# NG-Select Dropdown stuck behind divs

Tags: css, angular, angular-ngselect

Actually my `ng-select` it's like that, I'm using ng-gradient-able and `appendTo` doesn't work with me, how I can fix that manually in CSS?

Example Image]

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this on this thread.
https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select/issues/589

Basically, you need to declare that you want it appended to the body so that it is above all other elements in the DOM.

E.g. <ng-select ... appendTo="body">

Hope this helps